# Displaying multiple boxplots in R within a specific range

Tags: r, boxplot

If I have a data frame df with columns yearID and payroll

`boxplot(df$payroll ~ df$yearID, ylab="Payroll", xlab="Year")`


displays a boxplot for every year. Is there a way to specify the range of years that are displayed? Thanks

Comment: look at the last `?boxplot` example

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful to have the data that powers your code. You can read more about how to create an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

As rawr pointed out in comments, you can use the subset argument to `boxplot` to narrow the range of years that's rendered.

`boxplot(df$payroll ~ df$yearID, ylab="Payroll", xlab="Year", subset = yearID > 2013)`

Personally, I prefer using the data management tools from `dplyr` in order to keep my code consistent regardless of the function I'm using. In this case you can use `filter` to select only the years that you want. `dplyr` becomes even more useful when you use [pipes](http://seananderson.ca/2014/09/13/dplyr-intro.html), but I'll keep this example simple.

```
library(tidyverse) # Includes dplyr and other useful packages

# Generate dummy data
yearID <- sample(1995:2016, size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
payroll <- round(rnorm(1000, mean = 50000, sd = 20000))
df <- tibble(yearID, payroll)

# Filter the data to include only the years you want
df_plot <- filter(df, yearID > 2013)

# Generate your boxplot
boxplot(df_plot$payroll ~ df_plot$yearID, ylab="Payroll", xlab="Year")
```